# screen rotation not working on actual device but working in emulator

Tags: android

I have a weird problem. I set the screen orientation in android manifest and it works on emulater but not on the actual device. I also changed the orientation programmatically and still the problem persists. My manifest is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.rotatedsignage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rotatedsignage.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.rotatedsignage.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What is wrong with my code? The code I used -

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so exactly what is the problem? is it changing to LandScape when you change orientation?

Comment: try removing  android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: on emulator it is portrait but on the device it is landscape where it should be portrait.

Comment: The device is an android tv box if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your device under **Settings** section that whether your **AutoRotate screen is locked or not**.If it is locked then uncheck it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has no options for rotation. size and resolution are there though but no rotation.

Comment: just add this in your activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" and remove android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: but I want to keep it in portrait mode.

Comment: If you keep your device in portrait then it will be portrait or else landscape.

Comment: This is an android tv box that I am talking about. It has no g-sensor to automatically rotate the screen. So rotation has to be accomplished manually.

Answer (score 0):

First check your device settings as Siddharth Vyas suggest you, then make some changes like following in your config file.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
```

default means both landscape and portrait are enabled or else you can put portrait and landscape whatever you want in place of default. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the app in my android phone and screen rotation started to work. I think, for a real device, if changes are made in app.json, then app needs to be restarted to see the changes.